# Remove NULL values from columns

Tags: sql-server-2012, null, pivot, notnull

Using PIVOT

```
SELECT id, _TIMESTAMP, [Tag1], [Tag2], [Tag3], [Tag4], [Tag5], [Tag6]
FROM (SELECT id, _VALUE, _NAME, _TIMESTAMP
      FROM [dbo].[TableLogger]) AS SourceTable PIVOT (MAX(_VALUE) FOR _NAME IN ([Tag1], [Tag2], [Tag3], [Tag4], [Tag5], [Tag6])) AS PivotTable
```

my table looks like this:

```
id      _TIMESTAMP            Tag1  Tag2  Tag3  Tag4  Tag5  Tag6
1  2016-04-29 10:37:56.667    21    NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL
2  2016-04-29 10:37:56.667    NULL  0.2   NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL
3  2016-04-29 10:37:56.667    NULL  NULL  4     NULL  NULL  NULL  
4  2016-04-29 10:37:56.667    NULL  NULL  NULL  20    NULL  NULL  
5  2016-04-29 10:37:56.667    NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  35    NULL  
6  2016-04-29 10:37:56.667    NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  54
7  2016-04-29 10:37:58.667    32    NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL
```

The table has 30471 rows and can get much more. The execution of `SELECT` statement takes too much (like 10s). I tried to remove those NULL values with:

```
where  [Tag1] IS NOT NULL ;
```

If I wanna put simultaneously the same condition and for the [Tag2] column the table isn't anymore showed. I guess that those NULL values influence the time of SELECT execution. Is there a way to remove those NULL value so my SELECT statement executes faster? 
Many thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

My table I want to look like:

```
id      _TIMESTAMP            Tag1  Tag2  Tag3  Tag4  Tag5  Tag6
1  2016-04-29 10:37:56.667    21    0.2    4     20    35    54
2  2016-04-29 10:37:58.667    32    25     65    32    30    13
```

Comment: If youre trying to summarize by timestamp you need to remove `id` from your subquery that you are pivoting and the main Select statement

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you get better performance using Case Expressions instead of Pivot. To do a true Pivot though you can't have unique fields (ID) that aren't part of the aggregate or you get those null values

```
SELECT _TIMESTAMP,
       MAX(CASE WHEN _NAME = 'Tag1' THEN _VALUE END) AS Tag1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN _NAME = 'Tag2' THEN _VALUE END) AS Tag2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN _NAME = 'Tag3' THEN _VALUE END) AS Tag3,
       etc..
FROM   TableLogger
GROUP BY _TIMESTAMP
```

**Test Cases**

```
DECLARE @TableLogger TABLE (id int, _TIMESTAMP datetime, _NAME varchar(MAX), _VALUE FLOAT)
INSERT INTO @TableLogger VALUES
(1, '2016-04-29 10:37:56.667', 'Tag1', 21),
(2, '2016-04-29 10:37:56.667', 'Tag2', 0.2),
(3, '2016-04-29 10:37:56.667', 'Tag3', 4),
(4, '2016-04-29 10:37:56.667', 'Tag4', 20),
(5, '2016-04-29 10:37:56.667', 'Tag5', 35),
(6, '2016-04-29 10:37:56.667', 'Tag6', 54),
(7, '2016-04-29 10:37:58.667', 'Tag1', 32),
(8, '2016-04-29 10:37:58.667', 'Tag2', 25),
(9, '2016-04-29 10:37:58.667', 'Tag3', 65),
(10, '2016-04-29 10:37:58.667', 'Tag4', 32),
(11, '2016-04-29 10:37:58.667', 'Tag5', 30),
(12, '2016-04-29 10:37:58.667', 'Tag6', 13)

-- CORRECT WAY TO PIVOT
SELECT  _TIMESTAMP,
        MAX(CASE WHEN _NAME = 'Tag1' THEN _VALUE END) AS Tag1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN _NAME = 'Tag2' THEN _VALUE END) AS Tag2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN _NAME = 'Tag3' THEN _VALUE END) AS Tag3,
        MAX(CASE WHEN _NAME = 'Tag4' THEN _VALUE END) AS Tag4,
        MAX(CASE WHEN _NAME = 'Tag5' THEN _VALUE END) AS Tag5,
        MAX(CASE WHEN _NAME = 'Tag6' THEN _VALUE END) AS Tag6
FROM    @TableLogger
GROUP BY _TIMESTAMP

-- INCORRECT WAY TO PIVOT
-- Including ID will cause each row to only have one value
SELECT  ID
        _TIMESTAMP,
        MAX(CASE WHEN _NAME = 'Tag1' THEN _VALUE END) AS Tag1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN _NAME = 'Tag2' THEN _VALUE END) AS Tag2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN _NAME = 'Tag3' THEN _VALUE END) AS Tag3,
        MAX(CASE WHEN _NAME = 'Tag4' THEN _VALUE END) AS Tag4,
        MAX(CASE WHEN _NAME = 'Tag5' THEN _VALUE END) AS Tag5,
        MAX(CASE WHEN _NAME = 'Tag6' THEN _VALUE END) AS Tag6
FROM    @TableLogger
GROUP BY ID, _TIMESTAMP

-- WAYS TO INCLUDE ROW NUMBER OR ID IN PIVOT
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY _TIMESTAMP) AS [RowNumber],
        MIN(ID) [MinID],
        _TIMESTAMP,
        MAX(CASE WHEN _NAME = 'Tag1' THEN _VALUE END) AS Tag1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN _NAME = 'Tag2' THEN _VALUE END) AS Tag2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN _NAME = 'Tag3' THEN _VALUE END) AS Tag3,
        MAX(CASE WHEN _NAME = 'Tag4' THEN _VALUE END) AS Tag4,
        MAX(CASE WHEN _NAME = 'Tag5' THEN _VALUE END) AS Tag5,
        MAX(CASE WHEN _NAME = 'Tag6' THEN _VALUE END) AS Tag6
FROM    @TableLogger
GROUP BY _TIMESTAMP

-- A CORRECT PIVOT QUERY
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT  _TIMESTAMP, _NAME, _VALUE
    FROM    @TableLogger tl
) t
PIVOT
(
    MAX(_VALUE)
    FOR _NAME IN ([Tag1],[Tag2],[Tag3],[Tag4],[Tag5],[Tag6])
) pt

-- AN INCORRECT PIVOT QUERY
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT  ID, -- OOPS, included ID
            _TIMESTAMP, _NAME, _VALUE
    FROM    @TableLogger tl
) t
PIVOT
(
    MAX(_VALUE)
    FOR _NAME IN ([Tag1],[Tag2],[Tag3],[Tag4],[Tag5],[Tag6])
) pt

-- GIMME THOSE DARN ID's IN MA PIVOT
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY _TIMESTAMP) AS [RowNumber], 
        *
FROM
(
    SELECT  MIN(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY _TIMESTAMP) [MinID], 
            _TIMESTAMP, _NAME, _VALUE
    FROM    @TableLogger tl
) t
PIVOT
(
    MAX(_VALUE)
    FOR _NAME IN ([Tag1],[Tag2],[Tag3],[Tag4],[Tag5],[Tag6])
) pt
```

Comment: It does what I want but the problem is that not all the values are taken. I mean instead of 30471 rows, I get only 5120 rows. Any idea why's that happening? :)

Comment: And is there anything I could do to solve the problem?

Comment: @magn  have a better understanding of what you're trying to accomplish here.  You have shown us what result you're getting from your query, but you have not shown us what result you're expecting.

Comment: @magn  how is your expected result different than what this answer produces?

Comment: Gets rid of the NULL values.

Comment: @magn  I'm going to give up trying to help you now.. but i'll leave a full test case for you so maybe you can figure out what you're doing wrong.